# Presenting collections for code generation

Tags: object-oriented, array, collections, extension-methods, factor-lang

I've never been too bothered by the lack of `present` (and thus `print`) support for Factor collections and other objects, but I've never needed to generate Factor programs from JSON until now.

To that end, I use these methods to turn arrays, hashtables and assocs into roundtrippable strings:

```
M: f present
  drop "f" ;

M: array present
  [
    [
      dup string? [
        "\"" dup surround
      ] when
      present
    ] map
  ]
  [ length ]
  bi
  [ "%s " ] replicate "" join
  vsprintf "{ " " }"  surround ;

M: assoc present
  { } assoc-clone-like present ;

M: hashtable present
  { } assoc-clone-like present "H" prepend ;
```

The `array` method was written rather haphazardly as I tried to find something that seemed robust. The way the elements are finally formatted, using `replicate` and `vsprintf` may seem sloppy but it looks better than an `until`, and `sprintf` can't be used on non-constant values.

The recursive nature allows it to be cleverly repurposed for other collection types and on arbitrarily deeply nested arrays. Moreover, string literals in arrays preserve their `"quotes"` so they roundtrip too, which I initially struggled with.

But, can it be improved? The goal is that any collection converts into a string and `eval`s back into its original value (called *roundtripping*), which it does:

```
IN: scratchpad { 1 { 2 3 } "4" 5 } present ( -- x ) eval

--- Data stack:
{ 1 ~array~ "4" 5 }
IN: scratchpad H{ { 1 "a" } { 2 3 } { "4" 5 } } present ( -- x ) eval

--- Data stack:
{ 1 ~array~ "4" 5 }
H{ { 1 "a" } { 2 3 } { "4" 5 } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can it be improved?

Looks good to me.

Ship it.

The program accomplishes its goals, and it is clear. The length seems about right for what it does.